# Json dump of dict with tuples inside in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tuples, dump

I have a dictionary in Python which maps tuple to a number as follows.

The goal is to have my data printed in pretty json format, but I am getting an error

```
import json

data = {
        (7, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3): 2,
        (7, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3): 1,
        (2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1): 3,
        (7, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3): 4,
        (7, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2): 1,
        (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0): 2,
    }

print (json.dumps(data))
```

I am getting an error

```
return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

Apparently it has something to do with the tuple.

Casting data to string does not work, it only returns one-line result.

```
"{(7, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3): 2, (7, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3): 1, (2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1): 3, (7, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3): 4, (7, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2): 1, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0): 2}"
```

Comment: keys in json must be strings. Try this: `print (json.dumps(({str(k):v for k,v in data.items()})))`

Comment: Did you even read the error?

Comment: You don't want to cast the whole thing to a string, just the keys.

Comment: What's the point of converting this to JSON? No other language supports this type of object, so if you send it to another application what will they do with it? If you're just communicating with other Python code, use `repr()` instead of JSON.

Comment: @AntonvBR thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Barmar I will take a look at it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keys in json must be strings. Try this:

```
print (json.dumps(({str(k):v for k,v in data.items()})))
```

You can also use indent to make it prettier:

```
print (json.dumps(({str(k):v for k,v in data.items()}),indent=2))
```